# Facebook - Posting to other pages via api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

We have a desktop content management application.
our clients want an option to publish some content/articles from inside the application to their (business) pages on facebook (I'm assuming via providing their username/password).

1. is this even possible?
2. If yes, do we (our company) need a single account for the api or every client needs it's own account for the api?

What are the basic steps to archive this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Yes - [posting content to a Facebook page via the API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page/#publishing) is possible if you have the correct permissions.
2. You only need one application to post to all of the Facebook pages. The flow works like this:

   - An administrator (user that has permission to create posts on the relevant Facebook page) installs your Facebook application.
   - This user will need to provide the application with the `manage_pages` permissions. This permissions enables your application to [retrieve access_tokens for Pages and Applications that the user administrates](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#pagetokens).
   - The application will extract the relevant `access_token` for the specific Facebook page from the user's [`/me/accounts` endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/accounts/) (this is why the user needs to be an administrator).
   - The application will then use that `access_token` to be able to post the the relevant Facebook page.

Comment: So you say our clients need to install a facebook application on their FB accounts for this?

Comment: @user3906993 - Yes and no... First option, IMO, the easiest thing would be to allow your clients to log into your system using Facebook - part of this login will request the `manage_pages` permissions. After that you can allow the users to post via your system using the same methods I mentioned above...

Comment: Second option would be to ask your clients to add your user as an administrator of their page and then using your account, you can extract the page's access_token and publish the post.

Comment: I see, so the "Facebook application" option is the Third option or what?

Comment: The best way to get in contact with people that can help is to post here :P